# Filter WordPress posts by between parameter

Tags: wp-query, database, taxonomy, sql

How to filter WordPress posts by a taxonomy and between parameter? Consider a mobile website with "memory size" taxonomy, I need to show posts that have more than 256 mb memory and less than 768 mb.
Is it possible through WP_Query class or "posts_where" filter?
I know that post_meta is better for this purpose, but website has been built before.

Answer (score 3):

## Tax Query Limits

A [Taxonomy Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) in WordPress supports the following three arguments for the `operator` parameter: `IN`, `NOT IN` and `AND`. So it basically can't do what you're trying to do. Not even with advanced (`tax_query`) Queries.

## Meta Query and possibilities

You'll want to move your concept a bit and work with post meta fields/data. The `WP_Query` uses the `WP_Meta_Query`, which has some advantages over the `WP_Tax_Query`. The main one (for this question) is, that it supports more advanced relations through the `compare` arguments and you can as well sort by it: `'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'` and `'orderby' => 'meta_value'`.

> `(string) compare` - Operator to test. Possible values are `'='`, `'!='`, `'>'`, `'>='`, `'<'`, `'<='`, `'LIKE'`, `'NOT LIKE'`, `'IN'`, `'NOT IN'`, `'BETWEEN'`, `'NOT BETWEEN'`, `'EXISTS'` (only in WP >= 3.5), and `'NOT EXISTS'` (also only in WP >= 3.5). Default value is `'='`.

<sup>- Quote from the [Meta Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) part of the `WP_Query` documentation @Codex wp dot org.</sup>

So you could (should) switch your taxonomies that you want to order and filter/search by to become custom fields/meta data.

## Not possible? Stepped taxonomies for the rescue.

As I already explained on top of the answer, there's an `IN` operator for taxonomy queries. So what you could do is a call to [`get_terms()` <sup>Source: queryposts.com</sup>](http://queryposts.com/function/get_terms/) and grab all terms that are in your range and then build an array of taxons/terms that serves as your "limiters".

```
// Set "min/max"-limits:
$min = 256;
$max = 768;
// Get all terms in that taxonomy
$memory = get_terms( array( 'memory_size' ) );

// Container for our values
$mem_range = array();
// Check if we got an error
if ( ! is_wp_error( $memory ) )
{
    foreach ( $memory as $val )
    {
        // Convert to absolute integer for comparison
        $val = absint( $val );

        // Add to stack
        $val >= $min
        AND $val <= $max
            AND $mem_range[] = $val;
    }
}
// Debug
else
{
    // Output only for admin users and others that have that cap
    current_user_can( 'manage_options' )
        AND print $memory->get_error_message();
}

// Setup the basic arguments
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'hardware' );
// Check if we got some terms in range
if ( ! empty( $mem_range ) )
{

    $args['tax_query'] = array( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'memory_size',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $mem_range,
        'operator' => 'IN'
    ) );
}

// Grab the results
$hardware_search = new WP_Query( $args );
```

## Conclusion

While this might not be the best idea for high performance websites as you're doing two queries for a single task, it may fulfill ones needs. I'd still recommend switching over to meta data for more advanced, single queries.